# MySQL returning previous date's records instead of date mentioned in the WHERE Condition

Tags: mysql, date

**Goal:** To retrieve records for a particular date. 
**Problem:**
MySQL date is working in a weird way. It returns records for previous date instead of date mentioned in the condition.

I have tried DATE(), CAST(transaction_date AS DATE) and DATE_FORMAT() as well.
All return the same output.

For instance:

```
SELECT 
         transaction_date, 
         DATE(transaction_date) 
FROM table
WHERE DATE(transaction_date)='2021-11-19'
```

returns following output:

```
[{
"transaction_date":"2021-11-18T18:30:00.000Z",
"DATE(transaction_date)":"2021-11-18T18:30:00.000Z"
}]
```

[MYSQL Output][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hisAO.png

transaction_date has DATE datatype

This is happening for all the dates on the prod DB. However, it works properly on test DB.

I have tried everything I know. Can someone please help identify the root cause of the problem and guide towards solution?

Comment: The date in your JSON is that date converted to UTC (+00:00 or Zulu time)

Comment: This is probably India standard time (+05:30) converted to UTC so it is subtracting 5.5 hours

Comment: Alright. Why is timezone conversion taking place ? and how do I fix this ?